# Porting Promise.all functionality from AngularJs to VueJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vue.js, promise

I have this function that I need to move from AngularJs to VueJs and it has me stumped! Any help would be appreciated :)

```
items = {
    one: {...details here...},
    two: {},
}
```

AngularJs

```
var promises = [];
var deferred = $q.defer();

angular.forEach(items, function(details) {
    promises.push(details.promise);
});

$q.all(promises).finally(function() {
    deferred.resolve();
});

return deferred.promise;
```

What I have in VueJs so far

```
let promises = [];

for (let [name, details] of Object.entries(items)) {
    promises.push(new Promise((resolve) => {resolve(details)}));
}

return Promise.all(promises);
```

Thank you!

Comment: `items` isn't very representative. None of its values are promises. It's unclear what `Promise.all` and `finally` are for here.

Comment: Replace `promises.push(new Promise((resolve) => {resolve(details)}))` with `promises.push(details.promise)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for `new Promise` because `Promise.all` allows for non-promise values.

For a promise that resolves with `undefined` (this is what a deferred does) when all object values are settled (i.e. resolved or rejected), it's:

```
Promise.all(Objects.values(items).map(({ promise }) => promise))
.then(() => {}) // if it's necessary to resolve with undefined
.catch(() => {}) // if it's necessary to not reject
```

If all values aren't promises, there is no need for `Promise.all` at all.